# Iterator function python

Tags: python, loops

im trying to figure out how to make an iterable function in python, since im new to it i would appreciate any help, here is my code :

```
cra_initial = cra_func(a,b,c)
def cra(cra_initial):
   cra_annum = (cra_initial /7) *365
   'and so on some code contains a, b, c variables above'
   cra_adjusted = cra_func(a,b,c)
```

as you see in the last line of the code `cra_adjusted`  is using the same function `cra_initial`  in the first line is using, i want to get the result of `cra_adjusted`  and use it as an argument in `cra` function for like 20 times iterable

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: i think now its more clear

Comment: This question is about tail recursion and not about iterators.

Comment: im asking if it could be done by iteration, if not what kind of recursion

Answer (score 1):

I have found out an easy way of doing it here its

```
cra_initial = cra_func(a,b,c)
def cra(cra_initial):
    for i in range (1,20):
       cra_annum = (cra_initial /7) *365
      'and so on some code contains a, b, c variables above'

       cra_adjusted = cra_func(a,b,c)
       cra_initial = cra_adjusted
```

Its more effective

Answer (score 0):

I think this code would help you.

```
i=1

def cra_func(a,b,c):
    return (a+b+c)

def cra(cra_initial):
    global i
    cra_annum = (cra_initial /7) *365
    print(cra_annum)
    a,b,c=1,2,3
    cra_adjusted = cra_func(a,b,c)
    i+=1
# This condition will make cra() func run 20 times
    if i<21:
        cra(cra_adjusted)

if __name__=='__main__':
    a,b,c=1,2,3
    cra_initial = cra_func(a,b,c)
    cra(cra_initial)
```

Rest you can edit accordingly..

Comment: Variables must be used accordingly

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)